# Stop prompt() redirecting to input

Tags: javascript

For some reason I cannot find an answer to this, so here I am.

So, in my Java EE application I have this:

```
<a href="javascript:prompt('Make sure the text is selected,
then press either CTRL+C or right click and then \'Copy\'.', '{PASS}');" class="btn btn-success btn-md" role="button">{CHARS} Chars</a>
```

Now, when I press cancel on the prompt it redirects to 'null'. If I press OK it redirects to the text input.

How do I *stop* **ALL** redirects from this? Like, both cancel and OK.

Comment: That's not a proper use of the `href` attribute, use an event handler instead.

Comment: The `prompt` is simply providing you with its value. You will need to choose when it is appropriate to use that value within your application. You can't change how the `prompt` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Assuming you actually want to use JavaScript within a link such as with a bookmarklet:

The `javascript:` protocol has a hidden feature. If a value other than `undefined` is passed to it, it will be interpreted as a string and (essentially) passed to `document.write` to build a new HTML document.

You can test this out by seeing what `javascript:null` and `javascript:'<!DOCTYPE html><title>Hello</title> World!'` do in links.

The fix for this particular issue is to make sure you never return anything to `javascript:`, which is why you will often see `javascript:void(0)` in links.

### You probably *don't* want to use JavaScript within a link:

Rather than polluting your markup with unmaintainable JavaScript, put your script in a JavaScript file where it belongs. Also, since your link isn't being used to target a new document, use a `<button>` with some styles:

```js
document.querySelector('#example').addEventListener('click', function () {
  console.log('do stuff');
}, false);
```

```html
<button type="button" id="example">{CHARS} Chars</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not use `href`. `prompt` returns a null if canceled and the input if ok is pressed. This means your `a` tag is redirecting to the result of the prompt. Instead use `onclick`:

```
<a onclick="doPrompt()" class="btn btn-success btn-md" role="button">{CHARS} Chars</a>

function doPrompt(){
  prompt('Make sure the text is selected, then press either CTRL+C or right click and then \'Copy\'.', '{PASS}');
}
```

http://codepen.io/nilestanner/pen/KNpjeW